# Query regarding reading the file from within jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classloader

I am developing a spring boot application which would be used as a non-executable jar by some other user application. The spring boot application(jar) reads the xsd file present in resources folder. When we run it as a standalone application it executes fine.

Code to read the xsd file from resources folder -

```java
File xsdValue = new ClassPathResource("xsd/" + xsdFileName + ".xsd").getFile();
```

But the problem is, When user application calls the jar then it tries to find the xsd in its own resources folder rather than that of jar's resources folder.

Please advise !!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use a Path or InputStream with standard java ClassLoader.

Comment: And use unique paths. `Xyz.class.getResource("xsd/xyz/" + ...);`

Comment: [Retrieving Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html)

Comment: Thank you Joop Eggen.. Your solution drove me in the right direction and finally I got the solution to my problem..

Answer (score 0):

Resources in jar-files can not be gotten as File class, use getResourceAsStream method of ClassLoader class instead.

Comment: As suggested, I used  getResourceAsStream and it worked like charm..

Comment: Thank you Alexander lvanov for providing the much needed insight and suggestion.